# How do I temporarily remove an option in a select statement in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, optgroup

In my code I take advantage of the ability to disable and enable style tags to hide/show optgroup tags and their option tags. However when hiding optgroups this way in Microsoft Edge, it places a blank line instead of no line at all.

An example:

```
<optgroup class="my-option" label="truck">
  <option class="business">Business truck</option>
</optgroup>



<style id="enable_disable">
  .my-option {display: none; visibility:hidden;}
</style>
```

Then, in my javascript code I hide the optgroup this way:

```
document.getElementById('enable_disable').media = 'all';
```

To show the optgroup I do this:

```
document.getElementById('enable_disable').media = 'disable';
```

The same thing occurs if I do this just for the "business" class, except the user can select the option, he or she just can't see text, just a blank line.

Edit:
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rans8pew/2/) is a working example of what I am doing. You can see that it behaves the same in all browsers except for edge.

Comment: Is your code confidential?

Comment: I added some code so you could get a feel as to what I was doing

Comment: Can you tell me why I was downvoted?  Thanks.

Comment: @WIll your question was probably downvoted because it lacked a code example before you edited it

Comment: Ah, ok. I will make sure to put code examples in my future questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS to hide the children of a `<select>` element is not advisable (for now, at least). The results will be different across all major browsers. If you wish to remove an option, or a set of options, you should *actually remove them* with JavaScript.

Some inconsistencies between major browsers:

- Chrome, Firefox, and Edge will show the first item, even if it has *display: none*.
- Chrome, and Firefox will reactively hide the first item, if it is to be hidden, when another option is selected from the dropdown list.
- Firefox will allow you to select otherwise hidden values if you focus on the select element, and then press the up and down arrows to cycle through options.

If you maintain a reference to the removed element, [moving it around is trivial](http://jsfiddle.net/bgjvpd8o/).

Comment: Well the only major browser that seems to have a problem with this is edge. But if I have to remove it and then put it back I can do that.

Comment: @Will Check http://jsfiddle.net/fw18f485/; when the first item is the item being hidden, all browsers still show the item. Note also that Firefox will allow you to cycle through hidden values with the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I need to explain this a little better. I will be able to get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: @Will I see the issue, but as I suggested in my answer above, the best approach is to use JavaScript to remove the child element, and restore it at a later point. Attempting to use CSS to control the visibility will lead to numerous cross-browser issues. For example, notice how you can still select values "C" and "D" in Mozilla Firefox if you use the keyboard arrows instead of expanding the list (see http://i.imgur.com/LTibnxP.gif). I will file a bug for our team to evaluate the present behavior in Edge and consider our options (no pun intended, hehe). Thanks for sharing the issue!

Comment: Ah ok. No problem. Thanks for helping me find the best approach.